# synfig: animate a key going into a lock

Tags: blending, blend-modes, synfig-studio

I would like to animate a key going into a lock, so that as it goes in it hides the part already inside the lock.

[image]

How can I do it in synfig?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, I would bisect the chest image in half (given it is one image, if not, then import it into GIMP and flatten it, then place it back) right down the middle of the black keyhole. Then arrange the image levels like this:

Left chest image:  Bottom layer
Key:               Middle layer
Right chest image: Top layer

See [here](https://wiki.synfig.org/Layers_Panel) for how to manipulate the layers of an image. Then animate the key going across the canvas. If you are not sure on how to do this, see https://www.azdion.com/blog/basic-animating-synfig/.